# How to simplify WCF calls in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0, delegates

In Silverlight 4, all WCF calls made from the UI thread must be asynchronous. This is fine. The WCF client code exposes methods and events like

```
void GetDataAsync(SomeArgument a);
event EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs> GetDataCompleted;
```

**Is it possible to wrap it or configure WCF/Silverlight to generate the following?**

```
void GetDataAsync(SomeArgument a, EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>);
```

In my project I created a class responsible for all method calls, that is accessable to higher layers (like view model). It exposes methods like:

```
void GetData(SomeArgument a, Action<SomeResult> callback);
```

Now the `serviceClient` is reusable, so I need to unsubscribe from the *Completed event after the call is finished. My best approach so far is this:

```
EventHandler<T> MakeHandler<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{
    return (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        callback(eventArgs); // perform some operations in view model
        ((Action)eventArgs.UserState)(); // this is to unsubscribe from event
    };
}

void GetData(SomeArgument a, Action<SomeResult> callback)
{
    var handler = MakeHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>((s, ea) => callback(ea.Result));
    serviceClient.GetDataCompleted += handler
    serviceClient.GetDataAsync(a, new Action(() => serviceClient.GetDataCompleted -= handler));
}
```

I'd really like to avoid having to retype the whole GetData() wiring for every used WCF method and just do something like:

```
void GetData(SomeArgument a, Action<SomeResult> callback)
{
    serviceClient.GetDataAsync(a, callback);
}
```

Comment: What would you like to happen if Action<SomeResult> can't be called due to an exception. Note your ideal GetData can't throw an error during event handler phase. So what should happen?

Comment: BTW its a pity that Adam deleted his answer because he was on the right track.  Ditching the Async/Event pair for the Begin/End pair is a step in the right direction.

Comment: How would you ditch them and obtain the Begin/End pair? I have custom error handling which is embedded inside the SomeResponse class along with user-displayable message. No exception should ever be escalated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Begin/End ".NET Async Pattern" for your WCF service by using the Service interface of the ServiceClient.  For example if you have a WCF service called "Service1" your Silverlight project will contain a "Service1Client" class (that uses the Async/Event pattern to expose operations) but it also explicitly implements an interface called "Service1" which uses the Begin/End pair for each operation.   Use:-

```
Service1 service = new Service1Client();
```

Now with access to the Begin/End pair things get a little easier.  You can use the following Generic function to create the basic plumbing to calling the Async pattern:

```
    public static Action<Action<T>, Action<Exception>> AsyncExecute<T>(Action<AsyncCallback> begin, Func<IAsyncResult, T> end)
    {
        return (success, fail) =>
        {
            AsyncCallback cb = (ar) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    success(end(ar));
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    fail(err);
                }
            };

            begin(cb);
        };
    }
```

You can consume it with a specific function:

```
 void GetData(SomeArgument a, Action<SomeResult> success)
 {
      var fn = AsyncExecute<SomeResult>(cb => service.BeginGetData(a, cb, null), service.EndGetData);
      fn(success, GeneralFail);
 }

 public static void GeneralFail(Exception err)
 {
      // General reporting of fail
 }
```

Comment: Wow, somehow I failed to notice that the generated proxy has this explicit implementation...Thanks a lot!